# JSoup do not return all cookies

Tags: jsoup, session-cookies

I'm stuck trying to login in a website using Jsoup to get information from another link of the same site. When I connect it isn't returning all cookies from the session. I'm not sure if __utma, __utmb, etc.. should be used to keep logged but it's the only thing I can think that's stopping me to log.

Here's the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "https://www.evoicetelecom.com.br/customers/myAccount";

    final Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.evoicetelecom.com.br/login/")
                .data("userName", "user")
                .data("password", "pass")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();


    Document doc = res.parse();
    Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();


Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(url).cookies(cookies).get();

Elements element = doc2.select("body");

System.out.println(element);

    }
```

The print it's just to check if it's right or not.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but in my case the cookie value was empty (""), i found that the reason was that the cookie value was reset in the response header parser. Since Jsoup is open source its simple to debug the response handling. Try it out and you may find the answer for your problem. In my case I just added this little if statement to the cookie method in the HttpConnection.Base class:

```
        if(value.length() == 0 && cookies.containsKey(name)){
            return (T) this;
        }
```